# How can I install Bastille on a recent version of Debian?

Tags: debian, aptitude

To the best of my ability, I have looked everywhere in order to find a `.deb` file however even on its own website ([bastille-linux.org](http://bastille-linux.org/)) it is recommended to use `aptitude` which no longer seem to contain Bastille in its repository.

How can I download Bastille's installer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a package in this [link](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/b/bastille/bastille_3.0.9-12.1_all.deb). You can also download a `rpm` package and convert it to a `deb` format with some tools like `alien`.
You may use `dpkg -i package.deb`. But as far I know you must deal with dependencies packages manually, (Installing them manually)

Comment: Thank you! How did you find it? I searched and searched with no result.

Comment: Just search on Google "bastille-linux debian package" and check sites. Ubuntu-related sites has a lot of PPAs with many packages. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You may have better luck downloading a source package directly from http://bastille-linux.sourceforge.net/.  That seems to be the only Official source repository, with version 3.2.

The original "home site" for Bastille Linux was bastille-linux.org, but it was taken over in 2003 and doesn't seem to offer any support or contact information.

There is a recentl link to some patches that attempt to get more Linux distribution.
that is apparently part of the YOCTO project: https://www.mail-archive.com/yocto@yoctoproject.org/msg15086.html